# Call a function in a separate view controller?

Tags: xcode, view, uiviewcontroller

Say I have two view controllers. viewA and viewB which is a container inside viewA. Is there a way that when I am in viewB to call a function inside the main controller (viewA)?

I've searched a lot, and the solutions that are working for others don't seem to be working for me. This seems very basic, so I must have missed something...

Thanks to anyone that helps!!

Comment: viewB call view controllers B, then view controller B call view controller A

Comment: sorry, i meant for viewA and viewB to represent different view controllers, not actual views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewA.h

```
#import "ViewB.h"
@interface ViewA : UIViewController{   
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewB *viewB

- (void)functionA;
@end
```

ViewB.h

```
@class ViewA;
@interface ViewB : UIViewController{   
}
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) ViewA *parentViewController;
@end
```

ViewB.m

```
#import "ViewA.h"
```

Now you can call function inside viewA from viewB

Answer (score 2):

View controller A is view controller B's `parentViewController`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController